# Including a graphic in the contentsline of a Table of Contents

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, titletoc

In a dictionary, I have the first page of each section — corresponding to a different letter of the alphabet — marked to appear in the table of contents, using the `titletoc` package:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A}
...
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{B}
```

etc. This works just fine.

However, this is a dictionary of a language with a non-Roman script, and when I try to include a graphic of the letters immediately after the Roman letters in the TOC:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{A \includegraphics{graphic_a.png}}
...
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{B \includegraphics{graphic_b.png}}
```

I get an error:

```
.tex:3412: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@vspacer }\reserved@a 
l.3412 ...tion}{A \includegraphics{graphic_a.png}}
```

The instruction `\includegraphics{graphic_a.png}` etc. works without problems in other contexts, but apparently it won't work in the `text` field of `\addcontentsline{toc}{type}{text}`. Perhaps only actual alphabet text is permitted there. Section 7.6. "Inserting a ﬁgure in the contents" of the Bezos documentation for `titlesec` and `titletoc` describes a way to insert a figure *before* a TOC line using `\addtocontents` with `\protect`, but I haven't been able to adapt that information to what I am doing.

Is there another way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You should try adding `\protect` before `\includegraphics`. Elements being pushed into the ToC require this kind of handling.

Comment: @Werner: Same error. I've also tried the documentation's suggestion of segregating `\includegraphics` in a separate `newcommand`; same error.

Comment: Would you be able to update your question to include a minimal example that duplicates your problem. Also include the versions of the packages your using (add `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass` and extract the contents *after* `**File List**` in your `.log`). Why? Because a small MWE that loads [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) doesn't cause any problems if I use `\protect\includegraphics...`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks; it will take me a few days to make the time for this, but I am at work on it. Thanks for your patience and willingness to help.

Comment: `\protect` should work, as @Werner says, note however you may need to remove your .toc file. If corrupted commands have been written to it earlier, it will be input at the start of the next job and generate errors even when the source file has been corrected. A new .toc should then be written and a table of contents should appear on the next run.